# conjure-up openstack nova-lxd how to restart?

Tags: restart, conjure-up

I successfully installed openstack nova-lxd on a kvm virtual machine using conjure-up.

After a VM shutdown; when I start the VM openstack doesn't start.
lxc list shows one instance in "RUNNING" state and all the other in "STOPPED" state.

How can I start the other instances?

Comment: Does `juju status` return anything? The containers are set to boot on system start so that is a concerning issue on its own. You can run `lxc start <instance-id>` to bring them back up.

Answer (score 4):

I have this exact same problem.  I installed a brand new copy of Ubuntu 16.04 on my server, updated all the packages, then the only thing I installed was conjure-up and used that to install lxc openstack. `lxc list` showed all of the instances as up and running, I could login to the openstack dashboard, it was great.  Then I rebooted...now `lxc list` shows all but one instance as not running.  @gangstaluv to answer your questions in my environment:

> Does juju status return anything?

```
$ juju status
Model                             Controller                Cloud/Region         Version
conjure-up-openstack-novalxd-561  conjure-up-localhost-1e7  localhost/localhost  2.1.0.1

App                    Version      Status   Scale  Charm                  Store       Rev  OS      Notes
ceph-mon               10.2.5       active     0/3  ceph-mon               jujucharms    7  ubuntu  
ceph-osd               10.2.5       active     0/3  ceph-osd               jujucharms  239  ubuntu  
ceph-radosgw           10.2.5       active     0/1  ceph-radosgw           jujucharms  245  ubuntu  
glance                 12.0.0       active     0/1  glance                 jujucharms  254  ubuntu  
keystone               9.2.0        active     0/1  keystone               jujucharms  262  ubuntu  
lxd                    2.0.9        active     0/1  lxd                    jujucharms    7  ubuntu  
mysql                  5.6.21-25.8  active     0/1  percona-cluster        jujucharms  247  ubuntu  
neutron-api            8.3.0        active     0/1  neutron-api            jujucharms  247  ubuntu  
neutron-gateway        8.3.0        active     0/1  neutron-gateway        jujucharms  232  ubuntu  
neutron-openvswitch    8.3.0        active     0/1  neutron-openvswitch    jujucharms  238  ubuntu  
nova-cloud-controller  13.1.2       active     0/1  nova-cloud-controller  jujucharms  292  ubuntu  
nova-compute           13.1.2       active     0/1  nova-compute           jujucharms  262  ubuntu  
ntp                                 waiting      0  ntp                    jujucharms   17  ubuntu  
openstack-dashboard    9.1.0        active     0/1  openstack-dashboard    jujucharms  243  ubuntu  exposed
rabbitmq-server        3.5.7        active     0/1  rabbitmq-server        jujucharms   59  ubuntu  

Unit                     Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address  Ports           Message
ceph-mon/0               unknown   lost   0        10.0.8.183                      agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log ceph-mon/0'
ceph-mon/1               unknown   lost   1        10.0.8.209                      agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log ceph-mon/1'
ceph-mon/2               unknown   lost   2        10.0.8.141                      agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log ceph-mon/2'
ceph-osd/0               unknown   lost   3        10.0.8.159                      agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log ceph-osd/0'
ceph-osd/1               unknown   lost   4        10.0.8.115                      agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log ceph-osd/1'
ceph-osd/2               unknown   lost   5        10.0.8.216                      agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log ceph-osd/2'
ceph-radosgw/0           unknown   lost   6        10.0.8.48       80/tcp          agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log ceph-radosgw/0'
glance/0                 unknown   lost   7        10.0.8.61       9292/tcp        agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log glance/0'
keystone/0               unknown   lost   8        10.0.8.117      5000/tcp        agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log keystone/0'
mysql/0                  unknown   lost   9        10.0.8.123                      agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log mysql/0'
neutron-api/0            unknown   lost   10       10.0.8.96       9696/tcp        agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log neutron-api/0'
neutron-gateway/0        unknown   lost   11       10.0.8.140                      agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log neutron-gateway/0'
nova-cloud-controller/0  unknown   lost   12       10.0.8.238      8774/tcp        agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log nova-cloud-controller/0'
nova-compute/0           unknown   lost   13       10.0.8.190                      agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log nova-compute/0'
  lxd/0                  unknown   lost            10.0.8.190                      agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log lxd/0'
  neutron-openvswitch/0  unknown   lost            10.0.8.190                      agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log neutron-openvswitch/0'
openstack-dashboard/0    unknown   lost   14       10.0.8.111      80/tcp,443/tcp  agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log openstack-dashboard/0'
rabbitmq-server/0        unknown   lost   15       10.0.8.110      5672/tcp        agent lost, see 'juju show-status-log rabbitmq-server/0'

Machine  State  DNS         Inst id         Series  AZ
0        down   10.0.8.183  juju-ec5bf1-0   xenial  
1        down   10.0.8.209  juju-ec5bf1-1   xenial  
2        down   10.0.8.141  juju-ec5bf1-2   xenial  
3        down   10.0.8.159  juju-ec5bf1-3   xenial  
4        down   10.0.8.115  juju-ec5bf1-4   xenial  
5        down   10.0.8.216  juju-ec5bf1-5   xenial  
6        down   10.0.8.48   juju-ec5bf1-6   xenial  
7        down   10.0.8.61   juju-ec5bf1-7   xenial  
8        down   10.0.8.117  juju-ec5bf1-8   xenial  
9        down   10.0.8.123  juju-ec5bf1-9   xenial  
10       down   10.0.8.96   juju-ec5bf1-10  xenial  
11       down   10.0.8.140  juju-ec5bf1-11  xenial  
12       down   10.0.8.238  juju-ec5bf1-12  xenial  
13       down   10.0.8.190  juju-ec5bf1-13  xenial  
14       down   10.0.8.111  juju-ec5bf1-14  xenial  
15       down   10.0.8.110  juju-ec5bf1-15  xenial  

Relation                 Provides               Consumes               Type
mon                      ceph-mon               ceph-mon               peer
mon                      ceph-mon               ceph-osd               regular
mon                      ceph-mon               ceph-radosgw           regular
ceph                     ceph-mon               glance                 regular
ceph                     ceph-mon               nova-compute           regular
cluster                  ceph-radosgw           ceph-radosgw           peer
identity-service         ceph-radosgw           keystone               regular
cluster                  glance                 glance                 peer
identity-service         glance                 keystone               regular
shared-db                glance                 mysql                  regular
image-service            glance                 nova-cloud-controller  regular
image-service            glance                 nova-compute           regular
amqp                     glance                 rabbitmq-server        regular
cluster                  keystone               keystone               peer
shared-db                keystone               mysql                  regular
identity-service         keystone               neutron-api            regular
identity-service         keystone               nova-cloud-controller  regular
identity-service         keystone               openstack-dashboard    regular
lxd-migration            lxd                    lxd                    peer
lxd                      lxd                    nova-compute           regular
cluster                  mysql                  mysql                  peer
shared-db                mysql                  neutron-api            regular
shared-db                mysql                  nova-cloud-controller  regular
cluster                  neutron-api            neutron-api            peer
neutron-plugin-api       neutron-api            neutron-gateway        regular
neutron-plugin-api       neutron-api            neutron-openvswitch    regular
neutron-api              neutron-api            nova-cloud-controller  regular
amqp                     neutron-api            rabbitmq-server        regular
cluster                  neutron-gateway        neutron-gateway        peer
quantum-network-service  neutron-gateway        nova-cloud-controller  regular
amqp                     neutron-gateway        rabbitmq-server        regular
neutron-plugin           neutron-openvswitch    nova-compute           regular
amqp                     neutron-openvswitch    rabbitmq-server        regular
cluster                  nova-cloud-controller  nova-cloud-controller  peer
cloud-compute            nova-cloud-controller  nova-compute           regular
amqp                     nova-cloud-controller  rabbitmq-server        regular
lxd                      nova-compute           lxd                    subordinate
neutron-plugin           nova-compute           neutron-openvswitch    subordinate
compute-peer             nova-compute           nova-compute           peer
amqp                     nova-compute           rabbitmq-server        regular
ntp-peers                ntp                    ntp                    peer
cluster                  openstack-dashboard    openstack-dashboard    peer
cluster                  rabbitmq-server        rabbitmq-server        peer
```

> You can run lxc start  to bring them back up.

When I try that I get an error which probably explains why things didn't just come back up on their own:

```
$ lxc start juju-ec5bf1-0
error: Missing parent 'conjureup0' for nic 'eth1'
Try `lxc info --show-log juju-ec5bf1-0` for more info
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.  Is there something else I could check?  I've re-installed Ubuntu and conjure-up in case I had done something wrong but every time it works perfectly until a reboot, then it ends up in this state again.

EDIT-1: I didn't think to add the `lxc info` that it said to look at, adding that now.

```
$ lxc info --show-log juju-ec5bf1-0
Name: juju-ec5bf1-0
Remote: unix:/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket
Architecture: x86_64
Created: 2017/02/20 04:12 UTC
Status: Stopped
Type: persistent
Profiles: default, juju-conjure-up-openstack-novalxd-561

Log:

            lxc 20160220041252.329 WARN     lxc_start - start.c:signal_handler:322 - Invalid pid for SIGCHLD. Received pid 437, expected pid 452.
```

EDIT-2: I just fixed mine!

After much research I discovered the command `lxc profile show`

```
$ lxc profile show juju-conjure-up-openstack-novalxd-561
config:
  boot.autostart: "true"
  linux.kernel_modules: openvswitch,nbd,ip_tables,ip6_tables,netlink_diag
  raw.lxc: |
    lxc.aa_profile=unconfined
    lxc.mount.auto=sys:rw
  security.nesting: "true"
  security.privileged: "true"
description: ""
devices:
  eth0:
    mtu: "9000"
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: lxdbr0
    type: nic
  eth1:
    mtu: "9000"
    name: eth1
    nictype: bridged
    parent: conjureup0
    type: nic
  root:
    path: /
    type: disk
name: juju-conjure-up-openstack-novalxd-561
```

From the output of the `lxc info --show-log juju-ec5bf1-0` I surmised that somehow juju (or some other component) saw my other nic (I'm running this on real hardware as opposed to Mirto Busico on a VM if I read correctly) and was looking for a bridge called conjureup0 that didn't exist.  I suspect there is a bug somewhere which is why this was not created.  I think I could have done one of two things to fix this. 1) create the missing bridge 2) remove the eth1 device from the profile.  I chose the latter.

`$ lxc profile device remove juju-conjure-up-openstack-novalxd-561 eth1`

Rebooted, and now `lxc list` shows all my instances are up and running as expected and my dashboard works again.

Comment: Thanks socketwiz this solves the problem also for my installation on a virtual machine.

Comment: What does `snap list` show? I just recently fixed that issue where `conjureup0` wasn't surviving the reboot: https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/685, also keep in mind you do need `conjureup0` device as that's used with neutron

Comment: gangstaluv on my machine it shows: 

$ snap list
Name        Version  Rev   Developer  Notes
conjure-up  2.1.0    86    canonical  classic
core        16-2     1264  canonical  -

Answer (score 0):

@gangstaluv: retrying to do the install from scratch in March ends up with conjureup0 surviving the reboot.

After the reboot all the lxd containers are up and running but the rabbitmq-server in in error (for this I'll open another thread)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this kind of issue before, mostly likely the problem is with the network setting. By default, the value of MTU size should 1500 while first time deploy conjure-up openstack. My solution is to change the MTU size inside lxc profile configuration. You may also try on that.